# Unable to send EVT_COMMAND from one class to another

Tags: wxwidgets

I'm just starting with wxWidgets and I've run into a problem.

I have a mainwindow and another class derived from wxDialog. The main window launches the dialog box in non-modal mode. When the dialog closes, it posts an event but the handler for this event never gets called.

I'm using wxWidgets 3.1.5

The above two classes share a common header file, in which I have this code

`wxDECLARE_EVENT(EVT_VISOR, wxCommandEvent);`

This is my event table

```
BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(VisorFrame, wxFrame)
....
    EVT_COMMAND(ID_DlgDisplayLogsTerminated, EVT_VISOR, VisorFrame::OnDlgDisplayLogsTerinated)
....
END_EVENT_TABLE()
```

In the class derived from wxDialog, I have this at the top of my file

`wxDEFINE_EVENT(EVT_VISOR, wxCommandEvent);`

This is my event handler

```
void
VisorFrame::OnDlgDisplayLogsTerinated(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    wxPuts(_("VisorFrame::OnDlgDisplayLogsTerinated ent"));
}
```

And finally, this is how I post my event

```
void
DlgDisplayLogs::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& ev)
{
    wxPuts(_("send event"));
    wxCommandEvent event(EVT_VISOR, ID_DlgDisplayLogsTerminated); // enum value
    event.SetEventObject(this);
    event.SetString("Hello");
    QueueEvent(event.Clone());

    ev.Skip();
}
```

I have followed the documentation but I must be doing something wrong!

Comment: Dont use event tables, use `bind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're nearly there. I think what you could do is pass the `wxFrame` as a parent to your modeless dialog and post the event via the parent.

```
wxCommandEvent event(EVT_VISOR, ID_DlgDisplayLogsTerminated); 
event.SetEventObject(this);
event.SetString("Hello");
wxPostEvent(frameParentPtr, event);
```

And in your `wxFrame` event table:

```
EVT_COMMAND(wxID_ANY, EVT_VISOR, VisorFrame::OnDlgDisplayLogsTerinated)
```